# where in the Ruby or Ruby on Rails API doco is the Date "dweek" method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

where in the Ruby or Ruby on Rails API doco is the Date "dweek" method?

Example of usage:

```
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.1)
1.9.3p0 :001 > d = Time.now.to_date
 => Sun, 04 Mar 2012 
1.9.3p0 :002 > d.wday
 => 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's right here http://apidock.com/ruby/Date/wday

Comment: oh - but I'm looking at Date (not Time) and when I look at the Date API it says Date just extends object?